# Table Module vs. Domain Model

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I asked about [Choosing a method to store user profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429878/choosing-a-method-to-store-user-profiles) the other day and received an [interesting response from David Thomas Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429878/choosing-a-method-to-store-user-profiles#430044) suggesting I use the Table Module design pattern. It looks like this is probably the direction I want to take. Everything I've turned up with Google seems to be fairly high level discussion, so if anyone could point me in the direction of some examples or give me a better idea of the nuts and bolts involved that would be awesome.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The best reference is "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" by Martin Fowler:

Here's an excerpt from the section on Table Module:

> A *Table Module* organizes domain
>   logic with one class per table in the
>   database, and a single instance of a
>   class contains the various procedures
>   that will act on the data.  The
>   primary distinction with *Domain
>   Model* is that, if you have many
>   orders, a *Domain Model* will have one
>   order object per order while a *Table
>   Module* will have one object to handle
>   all orders.

Table Module would be particularly useful in the flexible database architecture you have described for your user profile data, basically the [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) design.

Typically, if you use Domain Model, each row in the underlying table becomes one object instance.  Since you are storing user profile information in multiple rows, then you end up having to create many Domain Model objects, whereas what you really want is one object that encapsulates all the user properties.

Instead, the Table Module makes it easier for you to code logic that applies to multiple rows in the underlying database table.  If you create a profile for a given user, you'd specify all those properties, and the Table Module class would have the code to translate that into a series of `INSERT` statements, one row per property.

```
$table->setUserProfile( $userid, array('firstname'=>'Kevin', 'lastname'=>'Loney') );
```

Likewise, querying a given user's profile would use the Table Module to map the multiple rows of the query result set to object members.

```
$hashArray = $table->getUserProfile( $userid );
```

Comment: Thanks, after a significant amount of reading and pondering the light went on.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation of what's the difference between them.

Comment: @BillKarwin Should data table entities **(defined in the business layer, BL)**, e.g. "User" or "UserProfile" here, have any data access concerns? For example, if the Data Access uses
attribute based mapping to materialize objects on data access. Should the BL data table entities carry those attributes? Would
it not couple BL to data access specifics? I am trying to establish the relationship between BL and DAL in a table module implementation.

Comment: @fallow, eventually you have to have *some* class that knows how to access the data in the way you store it. Remember that the purpose of creating "layers" in OOP is to preserve the flexibility to swap out different implementations. If you don't have that need, then creating more abstractions and layers has little value.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you very much for your comment. To be clear, you are **NOT suggesting combining BL and DAL** if the flexibility is not required. You **ARE** suggesting that having those attributes in the BL entities might be a suitable compromise; correct?

Comment: @fallow, it's hard to make a generalization without knowing the requirements of the project. But it's typical to make a **BL** class use a **DAL** object -- [favor HAS-A over IS-A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).