# Table module and table data gateway patterns

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I'm learning about patterns of j2ee, can anybody tell me what the differences are between table module(domain logic pattern) and table data gateway (data-source pattern)?
Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Table Module and Table Data Gateway are both table level patterns, but with a very fundamental difference.

A Table Module is a Domain Logic Pattern in the sense it can contain the BUSINESS LOGIC related to a particular table. 
A Table Data Gateway  is supposed handle Database interface only and is not supposed to contain any Business Logic. Read "database interface" here as "insert/update/delete/read rows from a table".

Please note Martin Fowler's definitions which clearly specify this distinction.

Table Module : A single instance that handles the business logic for all rows in a database table or view.

Table Data Gateway : An object that acts as a Gateway to a database table. One instance handles all the rows in the table.
( "handles" here typically refers to CRUD).

Comment: Remembering that Table Data Gateway and Table Module patterns are not opposites but working well together (Martin Fowler; Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture; Chapter 10 - Table Data Gateway - When to Use it).

Answer (score 2):

for table module see : [table module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433819/752366)

for table data gateway see : [table data gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782913/table-data-gateway-and-model/4783935#4783935)

The one is for mapping tables in database and the other is for mvc.